# Integration of BI(Business intelligence) with Portal

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

One portal which is hosted on a server and in another server there is a Business intelligence(tibco spotfire web) is hosted. i want to integrate BI with my portal .how it can be integrate?

note- my portal is in asp.net and Business intelligence(BI) is developed in Java and both are hosted on IIS.

Both server have full write to communicate each other.

my main concern is that we can hit on portal open my Business intelligence(BI)on client side.

Comment: How about using SOAP or Restful web services? Web services were made for interop between systems and servers. It also depends on what type of integration you want to do. Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

I think you make some API on your BL web site. (Using SOAP or RESTAPI)

if you use your BL with javascript on client side, please check JSONP.